# how to extract the url file containing jason.gz format ? i have pasted the url below . size of it is quite big

Tags: python, pandas, gzip

I have downloaded a file from http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon/productGraph/categoryFiles/reviews_Clothing_Shoes_and_Jewelry_5.json.gz and tried to unzip it and read it as JSON, with this code:

```
def parse(path):
    g = gzip.open(path, 'rb')
    for l in g:
        yield eval(l)

def getDF(path):
    i = 0
    df = {}
    for d in parse(path):
        df[i] = d
        i += 1
        if i==50000: #the no of rows we want read dont avoid this please
            break
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index')

clothsrevi = getDF('D:\\miniproject\\cloths\\reviews_Clothing_Shoes_and_Jewelry_5.json.gz')`
```

This appears to work, but how can I do it directly without downloading the file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Using outside links for your code is not an acceptable solution if you couldn't format the code properly - especially not links that can only work *on your own computer*. I have also edited your question to ask the question clearly and understandably.

Comment: As a side note: `eval` is a major security risk, and also does not correctly parse JSON. You should use the [`json` module from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) instead.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel   thank you so much got the idea about the formatting the question and i will try to use the json module u shared thanks alot for replying. Have a nice day....!